# AutoCompleteTextField not recognized as a textfield?

Tags: android

My question is, how do I make it so that AutoComplete will allow the user to skip to the next field, or hit the check button to finish entering in the field like normal text fields do? Right now I can not hit the next button to go to the next field or the finish button when entering data

EDIT: Talking about the built in android keyboard buttons not working on auto completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add attribute `android:imeOption="actionNext"` in your `AutoCompleteTextField` 
if still it is not working then also add attribute `android:inputType="text"` (text use just for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used unspecified instead of next, but this works, thanks again

Comment: if it is in last field you can use imeOption like "actionDone" so it will hide your keyboard.

Comment: Yeah changed it to unspecified and that works